# Sfumature diverse date dal passato prossimo e dall'imperfetto in questa frase

Tags: difference

Che differenza c'è tra queste due frasi? Si tratta di una differenza nella sfumatura del racconto però per me sono entrambe corrette. Non riesco a cristallizzare le differenze. In entrambi i casi l'attività è conclusa e finita (l'andare all'università) e quindi nemmeno quella spiegazioni mi aiuta molto a poter spiegare che differenza fa usare l'uno o l'altra.

*Dopo il liceo sono andato a Roma dove **facevo** l‘università.

Dopo il liceo sono andato a Roma dove **ho fatto** l‘università.*

In particolare con i germanofoni la differenza passato prossimo e imperfetto è veramente problematica e non ho ancora trovato una spiegazione veramente soddisfacente, completa e utile per chi l'italiano come lingua straniera.

Tratto da questo esercizio di Nuovo Espresso 2:

[image: esercizio]

Answer (score 3):

L'imperfetto rappresenta un'azione passata ripetuta o abituale.

A mio avviso, in quella frase, con il verbo *fare* è corretto l'uso del passato prossimo perché non hai "fatto l'università" più volte né era tua abitudine "fare l'università".
Con un altro verbo, ad esempio *frequentare*, si potrebbero utilizzare entrambe le forme:

- "frequentavo l'università", se si vuole porre l'accento sulla natura abituale e ripetitiva dell'azione
- "ho frequentato l'università", se si vuole semplicemente fornire l'informazione, senza aggiungere particolari valenze.

È da notare anche che, al di là della regola grammaticale, con alcuni verbi che di per se stessi indicano un'azione prolungata e continuativa nel tempo (ad esempio *vivere* o *abitare*) la scelta tra imperfetto e passato prossimo (o remoto) è molto influenzata dallo stato d'animo del parlante:

- Parlo il russo perché *ho vissuto* a Mosca -> è probabile che consideri concluso quel capitolo della mia vita
- Parlo il russo perché *vivevo* a Mosca -> è probabile che, più o meno consciamente, consideri la mia vita a Mosca non ancora conclusa e/o che, mentre sto parlando, la ricordi con nostalgia

Answer (score 2):

In effetti il problema di ambiguità nasce dal fatto che l'italiano è una lingua poco caratterizzata dal punto di vista dell'aspetto verbale (cioè l'azione intesa nella sua durata) e molto incentrata sul tempo verbale (cioè la collocazione delle azioni in senso cronologico-consecutivo). La differenza percepita nella sfumatura è data infatti dalla residuale differenza aspettuale che il passato prossimo e l'imperfetto hanno in italiano dove il primo è perfettivo (e cioè indica una azione "perfecta", dal latino "perfìcere", cioè concludere, finire) ed il secondo imperfettivo (cioè "imperfecta", quindi non finita).

Si percepisce quindi "ho fatto" come una azione passata e conclusa ; si percepisce "facevo" come una azione passata, NON conclusa e quindi prolungata nel tempo.

Entrambe le forme sono comunque corrette in quanto per la sensibilità di un italiano  è più importante precisare la collocazione dell'azione nel tempo piuttosto che la sua durata (compito che sia il passato prossimo che l'imperfetto qui svolgono in modo pressoché identico).